# Displaying posts in pages with navigation links

Tags: wordpress

I found several articles on the net about how to display posts in pages, but I can't find a simple solution for including navigation links except that one : http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/create-page-posts-wordpress-417.html

But it's not so simple. Perhaps there is a better way today with WP3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered marking your posts as a category and displaying them on pages using various post-to-cat plugins?

> http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/can-i-assign-posts-to-a-page

Comment: Uh.. Which plugin for example? I found one which displays posts of a given category in a page but it doesn't deal with navigation links, so it's all posts at once or nothing..